# Makefile: get the name of a file in a list without knowing the path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a list of sources in a set of directories by

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/**/*.cpp)
```

Let's say for example we have a directory like this

```
src
|- dir_one
|  |- file_one.cpp
|  `- file_two.cpp
|
|- dir_two
|  |- file_three.cpp
|  `- file_four.cpp
|
`- dir_three
   `-file_five.cpp
```

then `$(SOURCES)` is equal to

```
src/dir_one/file_one.cpp
src/dir_one/file_two.cpp
src/dir_two/file_three.cpp
src/dir_two/file_four.cpp
src/dir_three/file_five.cpp
```

I want to use Makefile functions to get a list of just the names of the files, BUT am oblivious to what directories there are. So for example I want to get

```
NAMES = <some makefile functions>
```

so $(NAMES) is equal to

```
file_one file_two file_three file_four file_five
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be aware that GNU make's wildcard functions don't have any special meaning for `**` the way that some shells do.  Using `$(wildcard src/**/*.cpp)` is identical in behavior to using `$(wildcard src/*/*.cpp)`; there's no difference between "match zero or more characters" (`*`) and "match zero or more characters followed by zero or more characters" (`**`).

Second, there are plenty of GNU Make functions that work with filenames; they are all shown [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html).

You could use:

```
NAMES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))
```